# Eclipse - won't add svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

i searched and i didn't find anything.

I have windows 7 x64 ultimate, eclipse luna(tried with juno, indigo too) latest ide for java developers, 1.6 subclipse(tried with 1.4 too) and java jdk 8(tried with 7 too).

I successfully installed subclipse to my eclipse(i've done this a million times before), loaded the jdk correctly on eclipse and when i press in svn repositories to add a new repository(in this case: https://xp-dev.com/svn/aCis_community/) it says Operation in progress... forever, it doesn't finish.

I tried adding a repository that begins with http:// (http://svn.l2jserver.com) instead of https:// and it was added successfully. Then i tried another one with https:// and still the same thing happens. I don't know if that's the problem though, however the svn works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem with both indigo and luna

Comment: Did you check the [Bugzilla for Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)? If your problem is not reported yet try to report it there.

Answer (score -1):

For svn installation on eclipse, we have follow two steps:
1. subversive plugin
2. subversive svn connectors

Follow these steps 
On main menu, choose Help > Install New Software. The available Software dialog appears.
In the Work with list,

1. select Neon - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/. A list of 
   software packages appears.
2. Expand the Collaboration node, scroll the
   list and select Subversive features Check other options in the
   dialog    as desired and click the Next button.
3. The Install Details  screen    appears in the dialog. Click the Next button, accept the
   license and    click Finish. Subversive will download and install.
4. It is recommended    to accept the option to restart Eclipse.
5. Go to Window > Preferences > Team (tree node) > SVN (tree node) > SVN Connector (tab) And install missing connectors

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)